# Notify admin via email whenever a course is added/published on Moodle?

Tags: email, notifications, moodle, moodle-api

Can we configure an email notification to admins whenever a course is published/added on moodle?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Event monitoring](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Event_monitoring) to subscribe to the \core\event\course_created event.

The full instructions are in the link, but a rough outline is:

1. Visit: Site admin > Reports > Event monitoring rules
2. Enable event monitoring
3. Create a rule and select the 'course_created' event to notify for
4. Create a message to send
5. Subscribe to the rule, via the 'Event monitoring' link on your 'User preferences' page